# Function to rotate an image various degrees

Tags: javascript, php, image, image-rotation

I am working on coding a research experiment where one of several preloaded images can be displayed rotated at a multiple of 45 degrees. Is there a function for doing this so I could have say

```
var img45 = function(img, deg) { ...
```

I need to be able to pass the pre-rotated images as variables to a different function.

I can't use CSS' transform since the same image needs to be available at several different angles and I can't just transform the canvas display because I need the pre-rotated images as variables.

Rotate() works but does not let me assign the picture to a new variable, it instead modifies the original image, which is not what I want (I need the original to be unmodified).

Answer (score 0):

```
var img45 = function(img_id, angle) {
    $('#'+img_id).rotate(angle);
}
```

Is this what you need?
It's jQuery, so you need to include jQuery's library.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```js
// Function to rotate element.
var rotate = function(elem, deg) {
  elem.style.transform = 'rotate(' + deg + ')';
}

// Test rotating boxes
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
for (var i = 1; i <= boxes.length; ++i) {
  rotate(boxes[i], (5 * i) + 'deg');
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```